# Can I access to ics file using webcal and add events directly without subscribing?

Tags: javascript, email, calendar, icalendar, webcal

I serve my own Ics file using webcal protocol. when I access the link I get a notification to subscribe to this url.

[image]

is it possible to change the ics file format to make it open directly the events without subscribing? (the same it happens when opening a ics file without accessing it through webcal)

Answer (score 0):

Shelef,
No you do not do such things in the ics format.

If you want to see the raw ics file, then drop the ics url into a browser url area, and change your browser settings to say how a .ics file should be opened (eg a text editor).  In my local setup for example in my preferred browser for testing I always open .ics files in notepad++.

If you are entering the .ics url in the icould add calendar window then yes of course it is going to prompt you to subscribe to the calendar, that is what that option does in icloud.

Please also note that webcal is an unofficial apple protocol for .ics files.  The official RC5545 protocol is http/s.